# Add a series to a chart by pasting its formula no longer works in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I used to be able to add a new series to a chart by typing or pasting a =SERIES() formula into the formula bar when a chart's PlotArea was selected, as indicated here: http://peltiertech.com/Excel/ChartsHowTo/ChartSeriesFormula.html

Some time ago it seems it become no longer possible. I'm using Excel 2010. I'm afraid I might have changed some setting that disabled this feature. Can it be reenabled? Or was it removed by a software update?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is caused by a bug in the July 2014 update to Excel. If you uninstall the update, the problem will disappear. Microsoft will ship a fix soon.

The support page for this update is here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2837600

That page also contains information about how to uninstall the update on your computer.